# Algorithm/method for grouping items based on their relative distance

Tags: classification, algorithms, distance

I'm looking for a method to classify a set of items based on their relative distance.

For example assume we have 4 cities and we know their relative distance:

| city1 | city2 | city3 | city4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 3.4 |
| 2.1 | 0 | 2.2 | 2.1 |
| 2.2 | 2.2 | 0 | 1.4 |
| 3.4 | 2.1 | 1.4 | 0 |

If we try to categorize these 4 cities into two categories, intuitively we'll end up with

```
(city1, city2) and (city3, city4)
```

by minimizing the inner distance between cities.

Based on my understanding of K-Means, this method works when we have a common distance metric to say X-axis. Here, we don't know how the distance is calculated, so there isn't a clear way to decompose distance to something in common.

Is there a method to categorize these cities?

Comment: long short answer, you can apply k-means to the transpose of your matrix X, so that each row will be a city

Comment: A simple option would be hierarchical clustering, where you can provide the matrix of distances directly.